# Why I can't use character "(" or ")" with the search and replace function in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

Every time I try to replace something, for example - the first 2 characters for each new line with something similar like `INSERT INTO Table VALUES (` and the last `(` is always skipped.

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you have the Regex Search Mode on.

For whatever reason, the program is using Regex to do the replacement as well.  Precede your `(` with a `\` to escape it.

`INSERT INTO Table VALUES \(`